# Change UIAlertViewController Tint Color

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am using google sign in for my swift application.  When the user clicks to sign in the API gives this `UIAlert`. Is there any way to change the tint colour of this?  I.e. the "Cancel" & "Continue"?

[image: UIAlertView]

I have even tried to change it globally using AppDelegate code below;

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = Color.brandPurple
```

This has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Just set tintColor of UIAlertController.

```
 alertController.view.tintColor = Color.brandPurple // alertController is the object of UIAlertController
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, (And duo to the name of the color you used and method you already tried, probably first option is what you are looking for)

## All alerts (and other stuff)

you can change the `window`'s `tintColor`

it could be accessed from any `view`

```
view.window?.tintColor = Color.brandPurple
```

## Just a single alert

Change that single alert's view's `tintColor`

```
alertController.view.tintColor = Color.brandPurple
```

Comment: I have added the first solution to the ViewDidLoad() however, it has no effect.  I believe I will need to find out how to access this specific UIViewAlertController from the GoogleSignIn framework.  If you know where I could locate it that would be great.

Comment: So the alert you are trying to change is in another `window`, try change the tint color of that window. You can get all windows from `scene/app delegate`